# When an instance field, a Collection of custom Objects, passes through my view, it becomes null. How do I prevent it?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot project. It uses both Spring MVC and Spring Security. The app gets `User` objects from a database and makes them updateable in certain ways in certain views. For example, this handler handles the request `/user/update-password`

```java
    @GetMapping("/user/update-password")
    public String updateYourPassword(Model model, Authentication authentication) {
        String username = getUsername(authentication);
        User user = service.getByUsername(username);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);
        System.out.println("user in handler: " + user); // LOG #1
        return "user-update-password";
    }
```

then shows the `user-update-password` view

```html
<form class="forms" th:action="@{/save-user(passwordChange=true)}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{id}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{username}"/>

            <fieldset>
                <label for="password">Your new password: </label>
                <input id="password" name="password" required/>
            </fieldset>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{name}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{lastName}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{department}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{salary}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{age}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{email}"/>

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{enabled}"> // to the best of my understanding, one doesn't have to

            <input type="hidden" th:field="*{authorities}"> // explicitly close input tags. i tried explicitly closing them too anyway

            <input class="main-button" type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

and finally gets it to the point where the password is encoded and the user gets redirected back to their home page

```java
    @PostMapping("/save-user")
    public String saveUser(@ModelAttribute User user,
                           @RequestParam(defaultValue = "false") String passwordChange, // some views that use this handler don't change password
                           Authentication authentication) {
        System.out.println("User @ModelAttribute: " + user); // LOG #2

        if (Boolean.parseBoolean(passwordChange)) {
            System.out.println("Encoding...");
            encodePassword(user);
            System.out.println("Encoding complete!");
        }

        service.save(user);

        return isAdmin(authentication) ?
                "redirect:/admin" :
                "redirect:/user";
    }
```

The password gets changed. The problem is the `authorities` field becomes null. Here's what LOG #1 returns

```
user in handler: User[id=2, username='mickey_m', password='$2y$10$ZE1cg7hP1CdafEhXITEfB.MNcyNxNUz1cm3ZTn.eRK13lHQfTta7i', name='Mickey', lastName='Mouse', department='sales', salary=180000, age=95, email='mickey@outlook.com', enabled=1, authorities=[Role[id=1, role='USER']]]
```

Here's what LOG #2 returns (I changed the password to "mimi" here)

```
User @ModelAttribute: User[id=2, username='mickey_m', password='mimi', name='Mickey', lastName='Mouse', department='sales', salary=180000, age=95, email='mickey@outlook.com', enabled=1, authorities=null]
```

**Why does this nullifying happen and how do I prevent this?**

You may need a bit more information on what `User` and `authorities` are. Here it is

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
// ...
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> authorities;
```

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
// ...
    @Column(name = "role") // the fact that the column is named differently may be important, idk
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    private Set<User> userList;
// ...
@Override
    public String toString() {
        return new StringJoiner(", ", Role.class.getSimpleName() + "[", "]")
                .add("id=" + id)
                .add("role='" + authority + "'") // notice quotes
                .toString();
    }
```

I tried many things, including adding a custom `Formatter` from `String` to `Set<Role>`. I expected it to, well, convert `String`s like `[Role[id=1, authority='USER'], Role[id=2, authority='ADMIN']]` (what I expected forms to return) into corresponding `Set`s of `Role`s. Unfortunately, it didn't help

```java
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
// ...
@Override
    public void addFormatters(FormatterRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("addFormatters() called"); // this log message gets printed on startup
        registry.addFormatter(new Formatter<Set<Role>>() {
            @Override
            public Set<Role> parse(String text, Locale locale) { // a breakpoint here never gets hit
                Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
                String[] roles = text.split("^\\[|\\]$|(?<=\\]),\\s?");
                for (String roleString : roles) {
                    String authority =
                            roleString.substring(roleString.lastIndexOf("=") + 1,
                                    roleString.indexOf("]") - 1); // -1 because of quotes
                    roleSet.add(service.getRoleByName(authority));
                }
                return roleSet;
            }

            @Override
            public String print(Set<Role> object, Locale locale) {
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope it may count for a "minimum reproducible example". Anyway, you can see the project's repo [here](https://github.com/NadChel/boot_security) in case I haven't included some important details

**UPD:** I discovered that it gets null in the view:

[image: authorities being null as shown via Devtools]

What should I make of this?

**UPD2:** You're not going to believe it! I cracked it thanks to the Sage chat bot! What worked is having this in my view:

```html
<!-- authorities is a Collection, and Collections don't have their toString() methods since they are interfaces and don't override it-->

<input type="hidden" th:name="authorities"
                   th:value="*{#strings.toString(authorities)}"/>
```

and also fixing my Formatter a bit:

```java
            @Override
            public Set<Role> parse(String text, Locale locale) {
                Set<Role> roleSet = new HashSet<>();
                String[] roles = text.split("^\\[|\\]$|(?<=\\]),\\s?");
                for (String roleString : roles) {
                    if (roleString.length() == 0) continue; // I didn't have an empty String check
                    String authority =
                            roleString.substring(roleString.lastIndexOf("=") + 2, // it used to have +1 instead of +2
                                    roleString.indexOf("]") - 1);
                    roleSet.add(service.getRoleByName(authority));
                }
                return roleSet;
            }
```

Comment: I'm afraid to add this to the question body (I don't want to get it closed for a lack of focus), but this `<fieldset>
                <label for="admin">Admin: </label>
                <input id="admin" th:field="*{authorities}" type="checkbox" th:value="${adminRoleSet}" />
            </fieldset>`
returns this: `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[Role[id=1,role='USER'],Role[id=2,role='ADMIN']]"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:67) ~[na:na]
 at java.base/java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:711) ~[na:na]`. May be rel

Comment: `adminRoleSet` is a model attribute: `addAttribute("adminRoleSet",
                        new HashSet<>(List.of(service.getRoleByName("USER"),
                                service.getRoleByName("ADMIN"))))`. It never gets to the `saveUser()` handler because of that error

Comment: First thing I would to is verify that it shows up correctly in the hidden field on the browser, and that it gets sent correctly in the POST from the browser.  That way you know where it first disappears, and can focus on that area.

Comment: @DavidA Hm, it disappears in the view, indeed: `<input type="hidden" id="authorities" name="authorities" value="">`. What should I do then?

Comment: My guess is that while you created a formatter to convert from a string to a set of roles, you didn't create a serializer to go the other direction (converting the entire set to a single string) when sending the response to the client.  Also, as an aside, not related to your question, you are letting your user change all the user settings by sending all the user details back and forth. The user could easily go in and change their department, roles, even salary with your current set up.  I would suggest only letting them send the new password, and not send all the user data.

Comment: @DavidA why would I need to "go the other direction" if `toString()` already does the job of converting anything to `String`s?

Comment: @DavidA well, as long as those inputs are hidden, they can't change those fields, can they? `department` and `salary` are always hidden in user views

Comment: You know what I just realized. `getAuthorities()` returns a `Collection` that doesn't have a `toString()` method. But why can I print it then? It's confusing...

Comment: A basic rule in browser/server development is never 'trust' the client.  Someone can always use development tools on their browser to change what is running locally.  So, they could debug and see the values, and change them.  So, non-technical users can't change them, but technical users can easily do so.

Comment: Good job on solving the serialization, though sending it all back and forth is still a security hole.